# Two different plugin installations in eclipse plugin directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the plugins directory in eclipse installation, there are directories and jar files.

What's the difference between the two? Why some of the files are deployed in a jar file whereas some are deployed as a directory.

[image]

I even found that some of the directory doesn't have a jar file inside, but some has one or multiple number of jar files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways of how a plugin can be built: Either as a jar or "exploded", which means it's a folder instead of a jar this is mainly interesting for plugin developers, e.g. files can be addressed directly when having a directory rather than in a jar, but for users, there should be no difference.

Having the same plugin multiple times means that you may have multiple versions installed. I'm not sure why... Maybe you installed them by hand seperately. To avoid this, consider using `Help > Check for Updates` instead of `Help > Install New Software...` next time.